# Http server showing the same page after refreshing?

Tags: python, http

I have a piece of code I am using for testing on `http servers`. What I did first was to set up my `http server in python and type it in my web browser, listening on port`8000`. However when i delete the`index.html`and stopped the`python` script and hit refresh on my webbrowser, it still shows the same page! I am currently using Firefox developer edition by the way.

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdYwQ.png)

I have tried replacing the `index.html` with another different website `index.html` for testing, but it wasnt showing the new website.

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

I expect the web browser to stop showing `index.html` after closing the `python` script. Please help to fix my code so that it stops showing the same `index.html`

Comment: maybe you have another server which works on port 8000 - but it would rather give error that port is busy.

Comment: or maybe browser uses some cache or work with page offline. Did you try with different browser ?

Comment: @furas I am not running anything else on that port. Could it be the `serve_forever()` which causes it to not exit forever? I am very confused. Is there any way to edit the code?

Comment: did you stop it using Ctrl+C or Ctrl+D ? Did you see any message that it stoped?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: your code is OK. There is nothing to fix here. Problem can be rather browser which can use data from cache. Or maybe you work in Offline (File -> Offline)

Comment: @furas i stopped it by closing the command prompt. Is there any way to see the cache or clear it?

Comment: I use Ctrl+C (in Linux) to stop it and I can see message `KeyboardInterrupt` . You can check if it still work using different web browser and programs like `curl` or `wget` which can download HTML from url. If they can download from 'http://localhost:8000' then servers is still running.

Comment: on Linux you can also use `netstat --all` to see all used sockets, and `netstat --all | grep 8000` to see if port 8000 is used.

Comment: @furas thanks! It was the cache issue. Hitting ctrl+ f5 solved the problem by clearing the cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the caching! Try hitting `ctrl+f5` in your browser to see if it works.

A bigger list of no-cache-reload keyboard shortcuts for various browsers can be found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache#Bypassing_cache